# Checking possibility of Wifi connectivity with Windows Mobile Pocket PC

Tags: c#, wifi, opennetcf, windows-mobile-5.0, smart-device-framework

i'm new to .NET Framework 3.5. Currently in my C# Project i'm using `Smart Device Framework`. 
My task is to enable wifi connectivity on a button click in a Windows Form as to **(Synchronize the mobile with the Web part i.e to get data from Web to Mobile)**

In `Windows Mobile 5.0 Pocket PC` i don't see any option for **WLAN connections** in 
`settings --> Connections`

Following are the List of Network Adaptors showing in the Windows Mobile 5.0 Pocket PC I see when searched

[image]

I configured with NE2000 Compatible Ethernet Driver.  **Am I going the right way ?**

Also I have added `OpenNETCF.net library` in the Reference of the Project
i took help from other stack overflow links and a microsoft documentation:
[Building a Wi-Fi Discovery Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446491.aspx)

Below is the code snippet :

```
/// Check available network interfaces
        foreach (OpenNETCF.Net.NetworkInformation.INetworkInterface networkInterface in OpenNETCF.Net.NetworkInformation.WirelessNetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces())
        {   /// network interface i get NE20001

            if (networkInterface.Description.Equals("NE20001"))    
            {
                /// Display current configurations
                textBox1.Text += ("Description: " + networkInterface.Description + "\r\n");
                textBox1.Text += ("IP: " + networkInterface.CurrentIpAddress + "\r\n");
                textBox1.Text += ("ID: " + networkInterface.Id + "\r\n");
                textBox1.Text += ("Status: " + networkInterface.InterfaceOperationalStatus + "\r\n");
                networkInterface.Bind();

                try
                {  
                    INw = (OpenNETCF.Net.NetworkInformation.WirelessZeroConfigNetworkInterface)networkInterface;    ///< Obtain wireless zero configuration interface                     }
                catch
                {
                    textBox1.Text = "Network interface is not Wireless Zero Configuration";     ///< Possible reason can be that image in WinCE 7 
                }

                accessPointCollection = INw.NearbyAccessPoints;

                textBox1.Text += ("Wireless Network available are:\r\n");
                /// Get available wireless network 
                foreach (OpenNETCF.Net.NetworkInformation.IAccessPoint iAccessPoint in accessPointCollection)
                {
                    comboBox1.Items.Add(iAccessPoint.Name);
                    textBox1.Text += (iAccessPoint.Name + " -  signal strength: " + iAccessPoint.SignalStrength + " (" + iAccessPoint.SignalStrength.Decibels + "dB)\r\n");
                }

              }
           }
```

i get INw value `NULL` below, because it has no WirelessZeroConfigNetworkInterface.

```
INw = (OpenNETCF.Net.NetworkInformation.WirelessZeroConfigNetworkInterface)networkInterface;
```

So INw.NearbyAccessPoints is not possible for WirelessZeroConfigNetworkInterface.

---

1) How to `configure WIFI connections` in Windows Mobile 5.0 Pocket Pc in .NET3.5

2) How to know if in current Windows Mobile 5.0 Pocket Pc the wifi is enabled or not.

3) Am i going wrong somewhere in my above code i.e is WirelessZeroConfigNetworkInterface required for enabling wifi ?

**Any suggestions would be really helpful**.

Comment: I fear you can not test WLAN and MS ZeroConfig without a real device. There is no WLAN emulation available for emulator as one is available for WWAN. Tehn, on idustrial devices, you may find that the real devices may not have MS ZeroConfig enabled but another supplicant like Funk Odyssey. For MS ZeroConfig you will find an article at MSDN at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446491.aspx

Comment: @josef  : (thanks for help) u mean to say the wifi connectivity can be configured on real device only ?

Comment: Yes, how want you to configure a WiFi card if there is no one available?